# Find the circle about the origin containing all roots of $X^7+X^2+1=0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

We need to  find the circle about the origin containing  all roots of $X^7+X^2+1=0$,
I am not getting any hint where to start from. It is a problem of Munkres General topology section $56$, chapter Fundamental Group.

Comment: Just for clarification - are you basically needing to find the magnitude of the "largest" root of the polynomial? That is, you need to find the smallest circle for which all roots lie within it? Or perhaps it doesn't need to be centred at the origin?

Comment: Your polynomial has $X^2+X+1$ as a factor, but the root with the largest absolute value is a root of $1-X+X^2-X4+X^5$ and can only be found numerically.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged "complex analysis" I thing a good approach could be to use Rouche's Theorem, so

**Hints:**

(1) Put $\,f(z):=z^2+1\;,\;\;g(z):=z^7\,$

(2) Check that on $\,C:=\left\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z|=\frac{5}{4}\,\right\}\,$ , for example,  we have $\,|f(z)|<|g(z)|\,$

(3) How many roots does $\,g(z)\,$ have within $\,C\,$ ?...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, It will be $7$, $Z^7=0$

Comment: Yup, indeed so.

Comment: It is altopo question from munkres, see my edit, I am not understanding ur answer :(

Comment: One may study topology a little before, together or a little after complex analysis, but it is my opinion that *algebraic topology* comes, **at least**, together with complex analysis and, probably, after that. Anyway, **you** tagged your question as "complex analysis" ...!

Answer (score 0):

This is Exercise 2 of §56 in Munkres. Logically it follows Exercise 1 as follows.

> Given a polynomial equation
> $$x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0 = 0$$
> with real or complex coefficients. Show that if $| a_{n−1} | + \cdots + | a_1 | + | a_0 | < 1$, then all the roots of the equation lie interior to the unit ball $B^2$. [Hint: Let $g(x) = 1 + a_{n−1} x + \cdots + a_1 x_{n−1} + a_0 x_n$, and show that $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in B^2$.]

To prove this, we simply notice that if $\frac{1}{x}$ is a solution of $g(x) = 0$, $x$ is a solution of the original equation. (WLOG, we may assume the $x=0$ is not a solution.)

We may use exactly the same trick for the case $x^7 + x^2 + 1 = 0$. We can prove that all solutions of $1 + x^5 + x^7 = 0$ must be outside a certain circle of radius $r$, and then conclude all solutions of the original equation must be within a circle of radius $1/r$.

Answer (score -2):

**Hint:** From the equation, you know that $X$ must be negative and less than negative one. You need to determine the relationship between $X^7$ and $X^2$ that allows their summation ($X^7$ will be negative) to be equal to $-1$.

Comment: less than negative one?

Comment: Thanks, having a rough morning it seems!